# How can I get the maximum byte array length from a string that has always the same length?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I have a fixed string with 245 chars, for example

```
v0iRfw0rBic4HlLIDmIm5MtLlbKvakb3Q2kXxMWssNctLgw445dre2boZG1a1kQ+xTUZWvry61QBmTykFEJii217m+BW7gEz3xlMxwXZnWwk2P6Pk1bcOkK3Nklbx2ckhtj/3jtj6Nc05XvgpiROJ/zPfztD0/gXnmCenre32BeyJ0Es2r4xwO8nWq3a+5MdaQ5NjEgr4bLg50DaxUoffQ1jLn/jIQ==`
```

then I transform in an array byte using

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
```

and the length of the array byte is `224`.
Then I generate another string, eg

```
PZ2+Sxx4SjyjzIA1qGlLz4ZFjkzzflb7pQfdoHfMFDlHwQ/uieDFOpWqnA5FFXYTwpOoOVXVWb9Hw6YUm6rF1rhG7eZaXEWmgFS2SeFItY+Qyt3jI9rkcWhPp8Y5sJ/q5MVV/iePuGVOArgBHhDe/g0Wg9DN4bLeYXt+CrR/bNC1zGQb8rZoABF4lSEh41NXcai4IizOHQMSd52rEa2wzpXoS1KswgxWroK/VUyRvH4oJpkMxkqj565gCHsZvO9jx8aLOZcBq66cYXOpDsi2gboeg+oUpAdLRGSjS7qQPfKTW42FBYPmJ3vrb2TW+g==
```

but now the array length is `320`.
So my question is: how can I determine the maximum length of a byte array resulted from a string fixed to 245 chars?
This is the class that I'm using for generating the random string

```
static class Utilities
    {
        static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        internal static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
        {
            byte[] randomBytes = new byte[randomGenerator.Next(length)];
            randomGenerator.NextBytes(randomBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. The first string is 224 characters long, and the second is 320 characters long. Where did you get the number 245?

Comment: The second string is larger than the first one. What are you asking, actually?

Comment: All those strings look like base64 encoded data. If that is the case, all the characters are in ASCII range.

Comment: @smarx and Groo I've added the code for generating the random string and I found where is error. Stay up for more then 48hour it's not a good idea

Comment: @Tinwor To clarify, the main issue is that you're picking a random number as the length of the original string, right? If you always use the same number of bytes to start with, the base64-encoded version should always be the same length.

Comment: Exactly @smarx it's a mistake generated by the lack of attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#page-4):

> In UTF-8, characters from the U+0000..U+10FFFF range (the UTF-16
> accessible range) are encoded using sequences of 1 to 4 octets.

The maximum number of bytes per UTF-8 character is **4**, so the maximum length of your byte array is **4 times 245 = 980**.
If you are encoding using the [*Byte Order Mark (BOM)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#page-6) you'll need 3 extra bytes

> [...] the BOM
> will always appear as the octet sequence EF BB BF.

so **983** in total.

*Additional Info:*

In your example, you also converted the byte array to Base64, which uses 6 Bits per Character and therefore has a length of `4 * Math.Ceiling(Characters/3)`, or in your case **1312** ASCII Characters.

Answer (score 1):

According to the design of UTF8, it is expandable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

In theory, you don't have a maximum length.

But of course, words in real world are limited.

In practice, byte lengths are limited to word count x 4.

```
245 chars => 980 bytes
```

If you look for a fixed length encoding, use `Encoding.Unicode`.

Also, `Encoding` provides a method giving maximum number of bytes.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(charCount: 245)
Encoding.Unicode.GetMaxByteCount(charCount: 245)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply, you cant. Universal Text Format 8 (which you use), uses 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes per char (like Tommy said), so the only way for you is to traverse all the chars (`GetMaxByteCount()`) and calculate it.

Perhaps, if you gonna keep using the BASE64-like strings, you don't not need UTF8, instead, you can use ASCII of any other 1-byte per char encoding and your total `byte array size` will be the `Length` of your string.